# Defining a coordinate system in WKT or PROJ format that has an Affine transformaiton and bounds

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3, affine-transformation

I need to define a local coordinate system via OGC WKT or PROJ form.

I know they have implemented Affine transformations in Proj 5 but I am unsure of how to implement it. The base projection is from `EPSG 28354` but we have file in the local coordinate systems with the below Affine transformation and Bounds

```
Name    SMG
Projection  Transverse Mercator, (also known as Gauss-Kruger)
Datum   GDA 94 Australia GRS 80
units   meter
Origin Longitude    Central Meridian
Origin Latitude used    central Parallel
Scale Factor    0.9996
False Easting   500000
False Northing  10000000
Affine Unit meter
Affine A    0.88866511
Affine B    -0.459520111
Affine C    3099033.308
Affine D    0.459520299
Affine E    0.888664756
Affine F    -6949726.605
Bounds  MinX    -10000
Bounds  MinY    -10000
Bounds  MaxX    500000
Bounds  MaxY    500000
```

I tried defining it with `FITTED_CS` but QGIS (our GIS software does not recognise that). Here is what I have tried:

```
FITTED_CS["test",
 PARAM_MT["Affine",
  PARAMETER["num_row",3],
  PARAMETER["num_col",3],
  PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.88866511],
  PARAMETER["elt_0_1", -0.459520111],
  PARAMETER["elt_0_2", 3099033.308],
  PARAMETER["elt_1_0", 0.459520299],
  PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 0.888664756],
  PARAMETER["elt_1_2", -6949726.605]],
 PROJCRS["MGA",
  BASEGEODCRS["GDA94",
    DATUM["Geocentric Datum of Australia 1994",
      ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0]]]],
  CONVERSION["Map Grid of Australia zone 54",
    METHOD["Transverse Mercator",ID["EPSG",9807]],
    PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.01745329252]],
    PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",141,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.01745329252]],
    PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,SCALEUNIT["unity",1.0]],
    PARAMETER["False easting",500000,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0]],
    PARAMETER["False northing",10000000,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0]]],
  CS[cartesian,2],
    AXIS["easting (E)",east,ORDER[1]],
    AXIS["northing (N)",north,ORDER[2]],
    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0]]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deriving a 2D affine transformed CRS from a projected one, is now named a *Derived projected CRS*, its keyword is *DERIVEDPROJCRS* and it is described in section 14.4 of the last OGC standarization document: http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/18-010r7/18-010r7.html

The 2D Affine parametric transformation Operation Method is registered as [EPSG:9624](http://www.epsg-registry.org/report.htm?type=selection&entity=urn:ogc:def:method:EPSG::9624&reportDetail=long&style=urn:uuid:report-style:default-with-code&style_name=OGP%20Default%20With%20Code&title=Affine%20parametric%20transformation&r=30).

The parameters have not the same name as provided in your question (maybe taken from `shapely`?), but I think that the following WKT could be the right one (if you can provide a control point coordinates in both systems we can check it):

```
DERIVEDPROJCRS["test",
    BASEPROJCRS["GDA94 / MGA zone 54",
        BASEGEOGCRS["GDA94",
            DATUM["Geocentric Datum of Australia 1994",
                ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433
                ]
            ],
            ID["EPSG",4283
            ]
        ],
        CONVERSION["Map Grid of Australia zone 54",
            METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
                ID["EPSG",9807
                ]
            ],
            PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433
                ],
                ID["EPSG",8801
                ]
            ],
            PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",141,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433
                ],
                ID["EPSG",8802
                ]
            ],
            PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
                SCALEUNIT["unity",1
                ],
                ID["EPSG",8805
                ]
            ],
            PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1
                ],
                ID["EPSG",8806
                ]
            ],
            PARAMETER["False northing",10000000,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1
                ],
                ID["EPSG",8807
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    DERIVINGCONVERSION["Affine",
        METHOD["Affine parametric transformation",
            ID["EPSG",9624
            ]
        ],
        PARAMETER["A0",3099033.308,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1
            ],
            ID["EPSG",8623
            ]
        ],
        PARAMETER["A1",0.88866511,
            SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1
            ],
            ID["EPSG",8624
            ]
        ],
        PARAMETER["A2",-0.459520111,
            SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1
            ],
            ID["EPSG",8625
            ]
        ],
        PARAMETER["B0",-6949726.605,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1
            ],
            ID["EPSG",8639
            ]
        ],
        PARAMETER["B1",0.459520299,
            SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1
            ],
            ID["EPSG",8640
            ]
        ],
        PARAMETER["B2",0.888664756,
            SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1
            ],
            ID["EPSG",8641
            ]
        ]
    ],
    CS[Cartesian,2
    ],
    AXIS["(E)",east,
        ORDER[1
        ],
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1
        ]
    ],
    AXIS["(N)",north,
        ORDER[2
        ],
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1
        ]
    ]
]
```

Saving it as a (e.g., `derivedprojected.txt`) text file,

```
projinfo -s EPSG:28354 -t @derivedprojected.txt -o PROJ
```

Returns:

```
Candidate operations found: 1
-------------------------------------
Operation No. 1:

unknown id, Inverse of Map Grid of Australia zone 54 + Map Grid of Australia zone 54 + Affine, 0 m, World

PROJ string:
+proj=affine +xoff=3099033.308 +s11=0.88866511 +s12=-0.459520111 +yoff=-6949726.605 +s21=0.459520299 +s22=0.888664756
```

Comment: Yep that did the trick :)