# Why won't this custom projection validate when testing it in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

Months ago I used some info on this site to create a custom CRS. It works fine for most of what I need such as creating maps, but functions like Warp (Repoject) and Define Shapefile Projection do not work.

Warp (Reproject) causes the following error:

```
 ERROR 1: Translating source or target SRS failed
```

While Define Shapefile Projection creates an empty .prj file.

The custom projection is as follows:

```
DERIVEDPROJCRS["Local Test",
BASEPROJCRS["GDA94 / MGA zone 51",
    BASEGEOGCRS["GDA94",
        DATUM["Geocentric Datum of Australia 1994",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]]],
    CONVERSION["Map Grid of Australia zone 51",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",123,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",10000000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]]],
DERIVINGCONVERSION["Affine",
    METHOD["Affine parametric transformation",
        ID["EPSG",9624]],
    PARAMETER["A0",-366765.199,
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
        ID["EPSG",8623]],
    PARAMETER["A1",0.999309400245847,
        SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1],
        ID["EPSG",8624]],
    PARAMETER["A2",0.0215194328107299,
        SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1],
        ID["EPSG",8625]],
    PARAMETER["B0",-7031641.581,
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
        ID["EPSG",8639]],
    PARAMETER["B1",-0.0215194328107299,
        SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1],
        ID["EPSG",8640]],
    PARAMETER["B2",0.999309400245847,
        SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1],
        ID["EPSG",8641]]],
CS[Cartesian,2],
    AXIS["(E)",east,
        ORDER[1],
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    AXIS["(N)",north,
        ORDER[2],
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]]
```

In the Custom Coordinate Reference System Definition dialog, the Validate button shows that the WKT project definition is valid. However, when I press Calculate in the Test segment, this results in a dialog box that says 'This CRS projection definition is not valid'.

For context I used a method found here: [Defining a coordinate system in WKT or PROJ format that has an Affine transformaiton and bounds](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353022/defining-a-coordinate-system-in-wkt-or-proj-format-that-has-an-affine-transforma) by Gabriel De Luca to produce this CRS.

How can I solve this issue?