# Create custom coordinate system from Microstation data

Tags: coordinate-system

I have the custom coordinate system data below from Microstation, but I don't know how to transform this data into parameters in QGIS customer coordinate system dialog box.  Is there a tutorial or workflow I can follow and learn how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Mike,
Read
[Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353022/defining-a-coordinate-system-in-wkt-or-proj-format-that-has-an-affine-transforma)
and
[Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387189/how-to-use-affine-transform-parameters-in-a-proj-or-wkt2-string)

Comment: Thank you.  I've read through those, but unable to understand the workflow.  I did find a SAGA tool "Set Coordinate Reference System", but I don't know how to generate the WKT.  Do I have to take my parameters above and translate that into a text string?  I don't know the format or order.  I was hoping there would be a wizard or some other input method where I could enter the parameters above in the right format and order.

Comment: No wizard available that I know of. I think I'm close to figuring it out from the 2 links. I hit a speedbump and posted [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/450757/custom-projection-error-in-qgis-missing-method-node). QGIS has error-checking, but it just tells you what's wrong, not how to fix it.

Comment: I followed that link where there were some corrections, but when I import it into Microstation, it's not in the right location.

Comment: Even though QGIS validates the WKT, I can't get it to work either. So I guess it's time for some [Reading](http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/18-010r7/18-010r7.html).